# How SSH protocol works relating to MaxSessions and MaxStartups

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I have a question related to `sshd`'s settings of `MaxSessions` and `MaxStartups`.

Suppose I have a host server that has `sshd` settings as below.

```
MaxSessions 3, 
MaxStartups 10,
LoginGraceTime 1m
```

And, currently 3 SSH sessions are established onto the host, and the sessions  will not end for a while.

At that time, a new (4th) SSH connection is going to be made while there are already 3 ssh sessions are on going.

The 4th SSH connection uses key-authentication, and there is NOT any problem with the key-authentication.

After key-authentication of the 4th SSH connection succeeds, what will happen to the 4th connection? Is there any correct scenario as below? If so, what is it? If the answer is #3, can you tell me the right answer for me?

1. The 4th ssh connection will be disconnected from the host since there already exist SSH sessions at its maximum. Total number of SSH sessions established cannot be exceeded.
2. The 4th SSH connection will be on the wait-list since even though there are ongoing SSH session at maximum, `MaxStartup` does not exceed its maximum. The 4th SSH connection will wait until there is any disconnection of ongoing SSH sessions made from the host, and the 4th SSH connection cannot wait more than the time that `LoginGraceTime` set, 1 minute.
3. Neither of the above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that neither of the two directives do what you think.

---

[`MaxSessions`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#MaxSessions):

> Specifies the maximum number of open shell, login or subsystem (e.g. sftp) sessions permitted per network connection. Multiple sessions may be established by clients that support connection multiplexing. Setting `MaxSessions` to 1 will effectively disable session multiplexing, whereas setting it to 0 will prevent all shell, login and subsystem sessions while still permitting forwarding. The default is 10.

In this context "session" is not a connection, it's a virtual channel within one connection. In most cases you will never face this limit, as most clients cannot make use of multiple channels. Or if they can, it is in less used/known scenarios.

---

[`MaxStartups`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#MaxStartups):

> Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated connections to the SSH daemon. Additional connections will be dropped until authentication succeeds or the `LoginGraceTime` expires for a connection. The default is 10:30:100.
> Alternatively, random early drop can be enabled by specifying the three colon separated values start:rate:full (e.g. "10:30:60"). `sshd` will refuse connection attempts with a probability of rate/100 (30%) if there are currently start (10) unauthenticated connections. The probability increases linearly and all connection attempts are refused if the number of unauthenticated connections reaches full (60).

So the "startup" limit is evaluated even before any authentication is done.